# I can't run anything on Ubuntu

Tags: apt, updates

after trying to update my Linux to fix some "issues" with this command:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

I totally screwed my system, now I have no sound, can't run any program, barely could figure out how to connect to internet, can't run video and neither terminal, also I've tried to boot another Linux from a USB-flash but when I select the option to "Install Linux" it resets and just run's the basic my corrupted Linux.

> *Edit:My question is what to do now? Because I can't boot from a USB in order to reinstall my OS, and I also cant run any app on my Linux
>   OS?*

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We're sorry, but Ask Ubuntu is not a forum, but a Question & Answer site: it works best if you ask one question, so you can receive one answer. When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas, which becomes unlikelier the more questions you put into, well, one question! ;-) So please, split up your question into multiple questions and drop me a comment so I can answer one of your questions.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

Comment: Try backing up the `/home` directory and erasing everything. That's a last resort, but it's what I would do at the end. I'd try cleaning up any orphaned files first, though it'd probably not help at this point.

Answer (score 2):

try choosing Advance options in grub menu.. and boot with the lowest kernel available

Answer (score 1):

I am not very expert with the terminal and all, but probably a clean install is the best solution. The error with the usb might occur due to a faulty installation of the media. My recommended program for writing isos to usb is Rufus for Windows (try to look for a windows machine to run the program, it even has a portable version). My second choice, which is available for Linux is unetbootin. I've had a lot of problems with that one, but try formatting the usb and repeating the process.